# Confused at regular expressions-Python

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
caps = "bottle caps/ soda caps/ pop caps"

regex = re.findall(r"\w[1-6]", caps)

print(regex)
```

output is:

```
[]
```

however if I do this

```
import re
caps = "bottle caps/ soda caps/ pop caps"

regex = re.findall(r"\w[1-6]*", caps)
```

ouput is:

```
['b', 'o', 't', 't', 'l', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'p', 's', 's', 'o', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'p', 's', 'p', 'o', 'p', 'c', 'a', 'p', 's']
```

how do I make it output:

```
["bottle caps", "soda caps, "pop caps"]
```

I know you guys would recommend using the `.split` but I wanna understand regular expressions more

I've tried this as well:

```
import re
caps = "bottle caps/ soda caps/ pop caps"

regex = re.findall(r"\w[1-6]?\s*\w[1-3]*", caps)

print(regex)
```

output:

```
['bo', 'tt', 'le', 'ca', 'ps', 'so', 'da', 'ca', 'ps', 'po', 'p c', 'ap']
```

whats happening?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R _I know you guys would recommend using the .split but I wanna understand regular expressions more_

Comment: `re.findall(r'\w+ caps', caps)` -> `['bottle caps', 'soda caps', 'pop caps']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be confusing `{1,6}`, which means "the previous pattern repeated 1 to 6 times", with `[1-6]`, which means "any of the characters in the range `1` to `6`".

So, what you have:

```
\w[1-6]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mIT6ZZv4-TvgGYj1)

… will match a word character, followed by a digit from 1-6.

---

Putting the `*` on the end just means 0 or more of that digit pattern, which means any word character followed by zero or more digits from 1-6.

---

But if you use the right syntax, you get what you want:

```
\w{1,6}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xtRsMJGaTmdVC69w)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `r"(\w+[\s\b]+\w+)"` which means: `\w+` = a word; `[\s\b]` = space or word boundary:

```
import re
caps = "bottle caps/ soda caps/ pop caps"

output = re.findall(r"(\w+[\s\b]+\w+)", caps)
print output # ['bottle caps', 'soda caps', 'pop caps']
```

---

```
(\w+[\s\b]+\w+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/5LvXG6BT8pb5ldBr)

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing yourself with what is actually a defined character class, `[1-6]` will match a single character between the range `1` and `6`. You were probably meaning `{1,6}` instead which will match the preceding regex token between `1` and `6` times, known as the range operator.

By preceding the character class `[1-6]` with the `*` operator in the second attempt, you're telling the regex engine to match the preceding token "**zero** or more" times, which ends up matching each word character individually because you have no numeric characters in your string.

Instead, you could simply write the regex as:

```
>>> re.findall(r"\w+ \w+", caps)
['bottle caps', 'soda caps', 'pop caps']
```